# Android wifi script problems

Tags: android, linux, shell, scripting, wifi

I have a problem that has been nagging me to an extreme extend in the past few days. I would like to write an Android sh script that does the following (to help me sync music, pics etc.):

1) Turn on wifi (wifi is off by default to save power)

2) Check if my wifi connection is in range (lets call it myWifi)

3) If myWifi is not in range, disable wifi, if it is in range, connect and start some synch software

Now, to enable / disable wifi, I use the following command, which requires root:

`svc wifi enable / disable`

To scan for avaible wifi connections, I use the following command:

`iwlist eth0 scan`

The strage thing is, that `iwlist eth0 scan` will only work if I am NOT logged in as root (I am very curious to why this is the case, if anyone knows anything?), running it while root will return:

`eth0: Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument`

but running it while not logged in as root, will give me the info I need. I have tried different approaches to get around this problem. The most obvious one is logging in as the standard user in the Android system right before invoking the iwlist command:

`su -c app_1`

However, any command that involves su will return `permission denied` even when invoking it as root, and since sudo does not exist in Android, I feel pretty lost here. I did also try a workaround involving splitting the script into two parts, and trying to run the first as root and the second as non root (the default user in Android i app_1), but this will only delay the problem...

If anyone has an answer to how to either get around this user problem, or how to use `iwlist eth0 scan` (or another command that does the same) while logged in as root, I would be very gratefull.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of wireless(number).h did you use?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not remember and I am afraid the script got lost with my old Nexus phone. I started using Google Music instead of the above script.

Answer (score 0):

According to [man iwlist](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist)  normal users can only see some left-over scanning results. To initiate a new scan as root you first need to start up your interface (after starting wifi):

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```